# What's the point of existential wand?

Tags: verifiable-c

I'm trying to understand the point of the "existential magic wand" operator.
I see that `(P * Q) -o R = P -o (Q -o R)`, which is clearly a form of currying,
and `|> (P -o Q) = |> P -o |> Q` is just a distributive axiom.

The axioms `ewand_TT_sepcon` (`(P * Q) && (R -o TT) |-- (P && (R -o TT)) * (Q && (R -o TT))`), `exclude_elsewhere` (`P * Q |-- (P && (Q -o TT)) * Q)`),
and `ewand_conflict` (`P * Q |-- FF -> P && (Q -o R) |-- FF`) confuse me.

What are the intended semantics of the existential magic wand?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. It's just `¬P * Q`, as opposed to the usual magic wand (`¬P ⅋ Q`).